# call python scripts from php encoding error for chinese params

Tags: php, python, encoding, exec, chinese-locale

i call python script from my php,this is a demo

when i pass english params like "abcdxx", it's fine

when i pass chinese params like "天河"(even) the return is "天河"

when i pass chinese params like "天河区"(odd),the return is "å¤©æ²³åŒ?"

my php file

```
<?php

$param = "天河" //天河区    abc
$keyword = exec("jieba.py " . $param);
var_dump($keyword);

?>
```

my python file

```
#coding:utf-8
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: Does your command line support utf-8?

Comment: when i run the python file  in the windows cmd， "xxxxx.py 天河区" the return is 天河区 @MarkBaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the bug.

I don't how to solve this problem, but I used another way.

I urlencode params "天河" in php，then unquote "天河" in python, it's done.